# If $\sum a_{2k}$ exists then $\sum a_m$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Let $\{a_0,a_1,a_2...\}$ be a sequence of real numbers let $s_n=\sum a_{2k}$. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n $ exists then $\sum a_m$ exists. Is it true?

I don§t find a counter example

Comment: what if $a_{2k +1} = 1$ for all $k$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Let
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}0 \text{, if } n \text{ is even} \\
1 \text{, otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = 0$, but $\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m = \infty$.

Comment: Great minds think alike I see. :)

Comment: It doesn't really matter which answer you accept, but you should accept one (if you're satisfied with the answer) so that it becomes flagged as "answered".

Answer (score 5):

Let:

$$\begin{cases} a_m = 0 \text{ if m is even} \\
 a_m = 1 \text{ if m is odd }\end{cases}$$
Then $\sum a_{2k}=0$ and $\sum a_m =\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I cant accept both but +1for both

Comment: @learnmore: Why can't you accept these answers. Both are prove that your assertions is wrong.